# Coloring one character only in jTextPane

Tags: java, textcolor

I am working on a project using netbeans.
I am trying to color only one character located in multiple places of a text in jTextPane.
I tried to use StyledDocument.setCharacterAttributes, but it allows me to color at least 2 characters, Which is not what I want.

For the moment I am using this code:

```
StyledDocument doc = jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();
javax.swing.text.Style style = jTextPane1.addStyle("Red", null);
StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
doc.setCharacterAttributes(5, 2, jTextPane1.getStyle("Red"), true);
```

Can any one help to solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of coloring a single character.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyledDocument;

public class ColoredTextTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = initgui();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static JFrame initgui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument) new DefaultStyledDocument();
        JTextPane textpane = new JTextPane(doc);
        textpane.setText("Test");
        javax.swing.text.Style style = textpane.addStyle("Red", null);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);
        doc.setCharacterAttributes(0, 1, textpane.getStyle("Red"), true); 
        panel.add(textpane);
        frame.add(panel);
        return frame;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The code you posted worked perfectly when I included it in my code. But because I am setting the characterAttributes in for loop it shows me just the same old problem. At least I understand that the problem is not in coloring statement. But It could be a problem in my own code. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation on [`setCharacterAttributes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html#setCharacterAttributes%28int,%20int,%20javax.swing.text.AttributeSet,%20boolean%29)?

You have the `length` parameter set to 2.  Set it to 1.

Comment: I did, I changed the length parameter to 1 but it does nothing. the color did not change.

Comment: StyledDocument doc = jTextPane1.getStyledDocument();

javax.swing.text.Style style = jTextPane1.addStyle("Red", null);

StyleConstants.setForeground(style, Color.RED);

doc.setCharacterAttributes(5, 1, jTextPane1.getStyle("Red"), true);

Comment: The color did not change?  Or the number of colored characters did not change?  The issue you had originally stated was coloring a single character.

Comment: Sorry for that. I meant the number of colored characters did not change. Actually, when I change the length parameter to 1, there are no colored characters at all.